# C# (Collection) Dictionary with Type as key

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, hashtable

I'm looking to create an Registry Collection where I could save some Data Driven Class and retrieve them easily. The first thought was to save them with an specific ID, but another way was to save their Type so I could retrieve them directly with a cast.

```
public class RegistryCollection<T> : Dictionary<Type, T> , IRegistryCollection where T : class {

    public void Register<A>(T entry) {
        this[typeof(A)] = entry;
    }

    public void Register(T entry) {
        this[typeof(T)] = entry;
    }

    public A Get<A>() where A : class {
        return this[typeof(A)] as A;
    }
}
```

```
public interface IRegistryCollection {
    T Get<T>() where T : class ;
}

public interface IRegistryCollection<T> : IRegistryCollection { }
```

**Small example:**

```
RegistryCollection<Item> itemsRegistry = new RegistryCollection<Item>();

itemsRegistry.Register<ItemChildExample>(new ItemChildExample());
itemsRegistry.Register(new ItemSecondExample());

ItemSecondExample item = itemsRegistry.Get<ItemSecondExample>();
```

I want to have your opinion as Casting is not every time the best choice and if they were already some Collection does this thing.

Thanks.

++

```
abstract class Item {

}

class ItemChildExample : Item { }

class ItemSecondExample : Item { }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this dictionary? What is the use case?

Comment: Saving,,Retrieving Items reference, Entity reference, Block reference for a minecraft like game. @DaveyvanTilburg

Comment: So if i am correct, you simply wish to deposit all game object in a single object for storage and later re-instantiate to load to game back up?

Comment: That's not really re-instantiate them because that's not "Data driven" way. Item are just pure data, giving property like texture, actions available etc.. And when i'm using them for example in inventory I create an ItemStack with an Item property inside it.

Comment: Is `Item` a base class or interface for `ItemSecondExample`? I would think you'd get a type error otherwise. What is the point of `RegistryCollection<Item>` if any type might be registered?

Comment: Exactly, `Item` is an base class and `ItemSecondExample` is an class that an inherit from `Item`. To stay on minecraft thing.. for example an Bow, Pickaxe, Sword.. etc..